# How to enable EditText auto-correct in my application even after the user has disabled their auto-correct settings on their phone?

Tags: android

Is it possible to enable auto-correct on my `EditText` field even after the user has disabled their `Auto-Correct/Auto-Complete` functionality through `Settings > Language & Input > etc...`?

I tried

```
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
```

and

```
android:autoText="true"
```

At first these lines of codes work, but after disabling auto-correct from `Settings > Language & Input > etc...`, I noticed that the red underline and word suggestions do not show anymore.

So my question is that is it possible to enable Auto-correct specifically for my app only? And if not what can I do to create an EditText that underlines misspelled words and shows suggested words even after the user disabled their auto-correct settings?

EDIT: It's because I am creating an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) for english words and the output of my OCR is sent to an EditText field. I want the functionality to check if there are words that are not in the english dictionary and underline them as red to help the user if there are wrong converted texts or the word just really doesn't exist in the English dictionary. So if they touch the underlined words, suggestions would pop-up. Although, we all know that most of the users disables this functionality :(

Comment: But what for? When user got it disabled it's not up to you to tell him he likes it otherwise

Comment: 100% agree with @MarcinOlowski.  If a user has disabled auto correct you should never try to reenable it. Clearly if the user has disabled it he doesn't want it.

Comment: It's because I am creating an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) for english words and the output of my OCR is sent to an EditText field. I want the functionality to check if there are words that are not in the english dictionary and underline them as red to help the user if there are wrong converted texts or the word just really doesn't exist in the English dictionary. So if they touch the underlined words, suggestions would pop-up. Is there any other way? Thanks for your replies